# do not source bash_profile or do not echo statements

Tags: linux, command-line, su, bash-profile

In the `~/.bash_profile` I have added some `echo` statement

```
echo "omg!!"
echo "$(date) welcome to $HOME"
```

When I run command like **`sudo su - foo -c 'ls'`**

**Output:**

```
omg!!
Thu Oct  3 13:44:41 IST 2019 welcome to /home/foo
1.sh 2.sh 1.out 2.out
```

actually I want output as **`1.sh 2.sh 1.out 2.out`** thats it

without changing in `bash_profile` and do not want to do any `tail/head` operations.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't start a login shell:

```
sudo -u foo ls
```

or, if you have to go via the root account,

```
sudo su foo -c ls
```

The `.bash_profile` file is sourced for login shells, but not for non-login shells.

Comment: Thank You! working